# Why is factorial not overflowing the stack in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

```
-module(demo).
-export([factorial/1]).

factorial(0) -> 1;
factorial(N) -> 
    N * factorial(N-1).
```

The factorial is not tail recursive but why is it not overflowing the stack? I am able to get factorial of 100,000 without stack overflow but takes some time to compute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Erlang process's "stack" is not stored in the stack given by the system to the process (which is usually a few megabytes) but in the heap. As far as I know, it will grow unbounded until the system refuses to give the VM more memory.

> The size includes 233 words for the heap area (**which includes the stack**). The garbage collector increases the heap as needed.
>
> The main (outer) loop for a process must be tail-recursive. Otherwise, the stack grows until the process terminates.

[Source](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html#id69762)

If you monitor the Erlang VM process in an process monitor like Activity Monitor on OSX or `top` on other UNIX-like systems, you'll see that the memory usage will keep on increasing until the calculation is complete, at which point a part of the memory (the one where the "stack" is stored) will be released (this happens gradually over a few seconds after the function returns for me).