# No Stack overflow Exception in Elixir while using regular recursion

Tags: recursion, elixir

Why is a simple regular recursion in Elixir not giving stack overflow exception even with very high number like n = 500000? It is neither tail recursion nor TCO.

```
def factorial(n) do
    cond do
        n == 0 ->
            1
        true ->
            n * factorial(n - 1)
    end
end
```

Comment: The answer in the question I voted to close this as a duplicate of applies to Elixir as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38968304/320615